# findCirclesGrid can't find sub-pattern with hollow insides

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find a unique 2x2 hollow center sub-pattern inside a circle grid pattern. Using  "detect", generates keypoints that indicate that the hollow circles are detected correctly, but the 2x2 pattern is not detected. Looking for a sub-pattern with full circles works.

The code could be boiled down to:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

orientation_grid_size = (2, 2)

params_orientaion = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params_orientaion.minArea = 200
params_orientaion.maxArea = 800

params_orientaion.minRepeatability = 1
params_orientaion.filterByColor = True
params_orientaion.blobColor = 255  # Detect only white centers

detector_orientation = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params_orientaion)


color_image = cv2.imread("1607961786.3423488.jpg")
color_image = cv2.cvtColor(color_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

status_orientation, grid_points_orientation = cv2.findCirclesGrid(color_image,
                                                                  patternSize=orientation_grid_size,
                                                                  flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_SYMMETRIC_GRID,
                                                                  blobDetector=detector_orientation)
print(status_orientation)

keypoints = detector_orientation.detect(color_image)
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(color_image, keypoints, np.array([]), (255, 0, 0),
                                      cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
plt.imshow(im_with_keypoints)
plt.show(block=True)
```

The original image:
[image]
The image with the keypoints:

[image]

Comment: [Contours](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html) is probably your best bet as you can request hieracy information that tells you which contours are inside which.

Comment: I will consider it. However, it seems to complicate things. Any ideas why findCirclesGrid failes?